# How to share code among different top-level repositories?

Tags: microservices, dry

My company has one repository that contains five top-level projects, which are all different "services" (that being the flavor of the month). Even though they're all in a single repository, they're deployed separately and treated as different applications. We have some common code that we would like to share between all five services (or some subset of them).

We want to put this code in its own top-level directory structure, but I'm not really sure where to go from there. The best I can think of is to symlink the folder into each project for local development, and do an actual `cp` before deploying. This seems janky to me but I can't think of another solution. How should I structure this project? The code is all Python if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a dependency manager like [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Create your top level directory with the common source code, define a `setup.py` file which will allow you to publish your common package to an artifact repository (e.g. [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). See [Nexus](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/pypi.html) for an open-source, private, artifact repository).

Then for all the projects that depend on your common code, define `setup.py` for each and list your common code [as a dependency](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies).

Comment: That's sort of what we were doing before, but it didn't work. That would mean that every time we wanted to update the shared code, we would have to make the change, create a PR (which would be intrinsically linked to another PR that used it), merge it, publish to a private repo, update the dependency in each of our five dependencies, etc. This makes local development practically unworkable.

Comment: I would recommend attempting to solve your problems with the dependency manager instead of ditching it. See "development mode" https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode for instructions how to develop on multiple projects together.

Answer (score 0):

From previous answer it seems that you're doing it correctly. With some adjustment of using development mode it would be even better.

I will like to suggest a completely different approach. Let's store all the projects in a single repository. When a developer needs to modify some shared code he/she can do it and modify his/her project. Both changes will be submitted in a single pull request. If the change in the shared component involves changes in other dependent projects that developer will alter them as well and summit in the same pull request.

By the way that's how Google works with their code base.